# How many Bloc/Cubit create in one project? Is that required multiple Bloc/Cubit in single complex project?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-bloc

Why single bloc multiple states not load on single page?

I am facing an issue Whenever i create bloc with multiple states and events when i call these on single page it will read only one event/state. so anyone can give me solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In single project you can create multiple BLoc and work with that. This is also standard practice in small as well large project which will manage your business logic module wise. In all project you need to manage your module and module wise or screen wise you need to create your bloc which will easily manageable.

BLoc make your work very easy if you have good understanding on this library. And apart from this if we talk about your issue then might be possibilities then you are not emitting new state....

If you share your code then I will help you..